# Why my predicate div/4 enters an infinite loop after giving me one answer?

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I'm trying to implement the [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) (a = bq + r) using Peano Axioms, so far I've done this predicates:

```
% Dd = Dr * C + R
div(Dd,s(0),Dd,0).
div(Dd,Dr,C,R) :-
    less(Dr,Dd),
    mod(Dd,Dr,R),
    times(Dr,C,X),
    plus(X,R,Dd).

mod(X,Y,X) :-
    less(X,Y).
mod(X,Y,Z) :-
    plus(X1,Y,X),
    mod(X1,Y,Z).

less(0,s(X)) :-
    nat(X).
less(s(X),s(Y)) :-
    less(X,Y).

times(0,_,0).
times(s(0),X,X):-
    nat(X).
times(s(X),Y,Z) :-
    times(X,Y,M),
    plus(Y,M,Z).

plus(0,Y,Y) :-
    nat(Y).
plus(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :-
    plus(X,Y,Z).

nat(0).
nat(s(X)):-
    nat(X).
```

Every predicate seems to work perfectly, the one problem I'm having is that doing:

```
?- div(s(s(s(s(0)))), s(s(0)), X, Y).
```

Gives me the correct answer, and then instead of saying there are no more answers enters an infinite loop.

I don't understand why div/4 do not stop, any idea why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: At first sight, there is too much testing of `nat(X)` going on. Can't we assume we are working with the _nats_ and just say a _nat_ is either the symbol _0_ or anything that looks like `s(_)` (where `_` is the "don't care what this is" variable)?

Comment: If you are using `nat(X)` as a consistency check while you are developing the code then I see no problem with their use. Once the code works then removing them should not change the result. Also it would help if you added test cases.

Comment: @GuyCoder For sure, but in this case I don't see the nats suddenly go off into tree structure territory  ... well, it's not really important.

Comment: I have to disagree with `it's not really important` If you don't learn the basic skills at first and learn how to apply them then you how can you know when to ignore them. I know that you have the skill to know when to ignore them, but does the OP have the skill? The level of the question leads me to believe they don't.

Comment: @GuyCoder trust me, I don't have the skill to ignore them.

Comment: If this is a homework problem, please post the exercise as given. It would help to know if the problem states that certain predicates or the head of a predicate has to be used.

Comment: @GuyCoder You are right, it _is_ important. Because `nat/1` doesn't only test, but also generates the naturals, i.e. is generating `s(s(0))` for `x` in case of "x+5=7".

Answer (score 1):

If you keep adding test cases you will find your problem. One of the predicates is wrong. Since I don't know how your method works because it is not like I was expecting based on the Wikipedia article I can make no more progress. Please answer the questions in the comment.

1. Create unit tests for each predicate. (which are below).
2. Create the new predicate `peano_number/1` as a proper type check by using SWI-Prolog [has_type/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=has_type/2) because `nat/1` would allow `nat(N)` where `N` is a variable, and that should not pass as a type check. A variable is not a Peano number.
3. Added more `is_of_type(peano_number,X)` as checks on input values, but also as checks on results of predicate. Once the code is working correctly, these can be removed and if the code is valid, all the unit test should still pass.

Working on the rest.

```
:- multifile
    error:has_type/2.

error:has_type(peano_number,Peano_number) :-
    peano_number(Peano_number).
```

```
div(Dd,s(0),Dd,0).
div(Dd,Dr,C,R) :-
    less(Dr,Dd),
    mod(Dd,Dr,R),
    times(Dr,C,X),
    plus(X,R,Dd).

mod(X,Y,X) :-
    less(X,Y).
mod(X,Y,Z) :-
    plus(X1,Y,X),
    mod(X1,Y,Z).

less(0,s(X)) :-
    is_of_type(peano_number,X).
less(s(X),s(Y)) :-
    less(X,Y).

% Cuts added to make predicates determinate
times(0,_,0) :- !.
times(s(0),X,X) :-
    !,
    is_of_type(peano_number,X).
times(s(X),Y,Z) :-
    is_of_type(peano_number,X),
    is_of_type(peano_number,Y),
    times(X,Y,M),
    plus(Y,M,Z),
    is_of_type(peano_number,Z).

plus(0,Y,Y) :-
    is_of_type(peano_number,Y).
plus(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :-
    is_of_type(peano_number,X),
    is_of_type(peano_number,Y),
    plus(X,Y,Z),
    is_of_type(peano_number,Z).

nat(0).
nat(s(X)):-
    nat(X).
```

```
% Added peano_number(N) because
% ?- nat(X).
% X = 0 ;
% X = s(0) ;
% X = s(s(0)) ;
% ...
%
% while valid is not useful for type checking.
%
% A Peano number can not be a variable.
%
% ?- peano_number(X).
% false.

peano_number(N) :-
    ground(N),
    N = 0.
peano_number(s(X)):-
    ground(X),
    peano_number(X).
```

```
:- begin_tests(peano_axioms).

nat_test_case_generator(success ,0       ).
nat_test_case_generator(success ,s(0)    ).
nat_test_case_generator(success ,s(s(0)) ).
nat_test_case_generator(fail    ,-1      ).
nat_test_case_generator(fail    ,1       ).
nat_test_case_generator(fail    ,a       ).
nat_test_case_generator(fail    ,s(1)    ).

test('nat success',[forall(nat_test_case_generator(success,X))]) :-
    nat(X).

test('nat fail',[fail,forall(nat_test_case_generator(fail,X))]) :-
    nat(X).

peano_number_test_case_generator(success ,0       ).
peano_number_test_case_generator(success ,s(0)    ).
peano_number_test_case_generator(success ,s(s(0)) ).
peano_number_test_case_generator(fail    ,-1      ).
peano_number_test_case_generator(fail    ,1       ).
peano_number_test_case_generator(fail    ,a       ).
peano_number_test_case_generator(fail    ,s(1)    ).
peano_number_test_case_generator(fail    ,_       ).

test('peano_number success',[forall(nat_test_case_generator(success,X))]) :-
    is_of_type(peano_number,X).

test('peano_number fail',[fail,forall(nat_test_case_generator(fail,X))]) :-
    is_of_type(peano_number,X).

plus_test_case_generator(01, success,       0 ,      0 ,         0     ).   % 0 + 0 = 0
plus_test_case_generator(02, success,       0 ,    s(0),       s(0)    ).   % 0 + 1 = 1
plus_test_case_generator(03, success,       0 , s(s(0)),     s(s(0))   ).   % 0 + 2 = 2
plus_test_case_generator(04, success,     s(0),      0 ,       s(0)    ).   % 1 + 0 = 1
plus_test_case_generator(05, success,     s(0),    s(0),     s(s(0))   ).   % 1 + 1 = 2
plus_test_case_generator(06, success,     s(0), s(s(0)),   s(s(s(0)))  ).   % 1 + 2 = 3
plus_test_case_generator(07, success,  s(s(0)),      0 ,     s(s(0))   ).   % 2 + 0 = 2
plus_test_case_generator(08, success,  s(s(0)),    s(0),   s(s(s(0)))  ).   % 2 + 1 = 3
plus_test_case_generator(09, success,  s(s(0)), s(s(0)), s(s(s(s(0)))) ).   % 2 + 2 = 4
plus_test_case_generator(10, fail   ,     s(1), s(s(0)), s(s(s(s(0)))) ).   % s(1) is not a valid Peano number
plus_test_case_generator(11, fail   ,  s(s(0)),       a, s(s(s(s(0)))) ).   % a is not a valid Peano number
plus_test_case_generator(12, fail   ,  s(s(0)), s(s(0)),         3     ).   % 3 is not a valid Peano number
plus_test_case_generator(13, fail   ,  s(s(0)), s(s(0)),   s(s(s(0)))  ).   % 2 + 2 does not equal 3

test('plus success',[forall(plus_test_case_generator(_,success,A,B,C))]) :-
    plus(A,B,C).

test('plus fail',[fail,forall(plus_test_case_generator(_,fail,A,B,C))]) :-
    plus(A,B,C).

times_test_case_generator(01, success,       0 ,      0 ,         0     ).   % 0 * 0 = 0
times_test_case_generator(02, success,       0 ,    s(0),         0     ).   % 0 * 1 = 0
times_test_case_generator(03, success,       0 , s(s(0)),         0     ).   % 0 * 2 = 0
times_test_case_generator(04, success,     s(0),      0 ,         0     ).   % 1 * 0 = 0
times_test_case_generator(05, success,     s(0),    s(0),       s(0)    ).   % 1 * 1 = 1
times_test_case_generator(06, success,     s(0), s(s(0)),     s(s(0))   ).   % 1 * 2 = 2
times_test_case_generator(07, success,  s(s(0)),      0 ,         0     ).   % 2 * 0 = 0
times_test_case_generator(08, success,  s(s(0)),    s(0),     s(s(0))   ).   % 2 * 1 = 2
times_test_case_generator(09, success,  s(s(0)), s(s(0)), s(s(s(s(0)))) ).   % 2 * 2 = 4
times_test_case_generator(10, fail   ,     s(1), s(s(0)), s(s(s(s(0)))) ).   % s(1) is not a valid Peano number
times_test_case_generator(11, fail   ,  s(s(0)),       a, s(s(s(s(0)))) ).   % a is not a valid Peano number
times_test_case_generator(12, fail   ,  s(s(0)), s(s(0)),         3     ).   % 3 is not a valid Peano number
times_test_case_generator(13, fail   ,  s(s(0)), s(s(0)),   s(s(s(0)))  ).   % 2 * 2 does not equal 3

test('times success',[forall(times_test_case_generator(_,success,A,B,C))]) :-
    times(A,B,C).

:- end_tests(peano_axioms).
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite get my head around this code. If I understand correctly, it tries to find a divisor and a remainder by trying successively larger divisors. Because the `div/4` just states the properties of divisor and remainder i.e. it *tests* whether anything found is appropriate. The *generate* part is buried in `times/3` which generates possible `C` for *Dr*C=X*.

I found this:

- I don't know what `mod/3` does.
- `times/3` has a problem because there is ambiguity on two clauses
- `nat/1` is not a test, but a generator of natural numbers
- the infinite loop comes from the fact that `div/4` does not know that if it has found one solution, there are no more solutions. If will try successively larger divisor. We can tell it to stop at the far end of the clause, where a solution has been found, via a cut.
- One must pay

This leads to:

```
div(Dd,s(0),Dd,0).
div(Dd,Dr,C,R) :-    
    % just a guard
    less(Dr,Dd), 
    % Dr known, C,X free, 
    % --> C should be incremented by 1 on backtracking, and X computed
    % --> and we will stop latest when X > Dd
    times(Dr,C,X), 
    % --> Dd known, X has been generated by the above, R is being computed
    plus(X,R,Dd),
    less(R,Dr),
    % solution found at this point
    !.

less(0,s(_)).
less(s(X),s(Y)) :-
    less(X,Y).

times(0,_,0).
times(s(X),Y,Z) :-
    times(X,Y,M),
    plus(Y,M,Z).

plus(0,Y,Y) :-
    nat(Y).
plus(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :-
    plus(X,Y,Z).

nat(0).
nat(s(X)):-
    nat(X).
```

## Addendum

As said earlier it is easier to replace Peano recursive definitions by the easier to-read list of ... aynthing really. In this case, the anonymous variable `_`. If Peano had known about lists, he would probably have used these instead (same as for Gödel, who would probably have [used proper arrays instead of heroic Gödel encoding](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec3.html))

For example for `times/3` (note the disambiguation of `[_|Rs]`, which aliases to `[_]` and `[_,_|Rs]`,  into two distinct cases `[_]` and `[_,_|Rs]`; I was stumped by this for some time) and `plus/3`:

```
times([],X,[])      :- nat(X).
times([_],X,X)      :- nat(X).
times([_,S|Rs],Y,Z) :- times([S|Rs],Y,M),plus(Y,M,Z).

% adding two lists

plus([],Y,Y)        :- nat(Y).
plus([_|X],Y,[_|Z]) :- plus(X,Y,Z).

% a list of any length is equivalent to a natural number
% this predicate not only tests, but also constructs natural
% numbers; try "nat(X)"

nat([]).
nat([_|X]) :- nat(X).
```

The above can be tested. The tests for `plus/3` work well:

```
:- begin_tests(plus).

% 0 variables (thus a test)

test('0+0=0') :- plus([],[],[]).
test('1+1=2') :- plus([_],[_],[_,_]).
test('2+2=4') :- plus([_,_],[_,_],[_,_,_,_]).

% 1 variable

test('x+1=2') :- bagof(X,plus(X,[_],[_,_]),L),L=[[_]].
test('1+x=2') :- bagof(X,plus([_],X,[_,_]),L),L=[[_]].
test('1+1=x') :- bagof(X,plus([_],[_],X),L),L=[[_,_]].
test('3+x=5') :- bagof(X,plus([_,_,_],X,[_,_,_,_,_]),L),L=[[_,_]].
test('x+3=5') :- bagof(X,plus(X,[_,_,_],[_,_,_,_,_]),L),L=[[_,_]].

% 2 variables 

test('x+y=3') :- bagof(sol(X,Y),plus(X,Y,[_,_,_]),L), L= [sol([], [_,_,_]), sol([_], [_, _]), sol([_, _], [_]), sol([_, _, _], [])].
% test('3+x=y') :- ...  plus([_,_,_],X,Y) generates infinitely many solutions; good; how to run this 5 times for example??
% test('x+3=y') :- ...  plus([_,_,_],X,Y) generates infinitely many solutions; good; how to run this 5 times for example??

% 3 variables (goes to infinity)

% we cannot test plus(X,Y,Z); the coolest would be for plus/3 to then generate
% all possible X,Y,Z triplets with increasing Z for example. How to do that?

:- end_tests(plus).
```

```
?- run_tests(plus).
% PL-Unit: plus ......... done
% All 9 tests passed
true.
```

But the tests for `times/3` go into infinity after the first successful result. I'm not happy about that.

```
:- begin_tests(times).

% 0 variables

test('0*0=0') :- times([],[],[]).
test('0*2=0') :- times([],[_,_],[]).
test('2*0=0') :- times([_,_],[],[]).

test('1*1=1') :- times([_],[_],[_]).
test('1*2=1') :- times([_],[_,_],[_]).
test('2*1=1') :- times([_,_],[_],[_]).

% element 0 does not work

% test('0*x=0') :- generates all naturals
% test('x*0=0') :- generates all naturals
% test('x*y=0') :- generates all pairs of naturals

test('1*x=1') :- bagof(X,times([_],X,[_]),L),L=[[_]].
test('2*x=4') :- bagof(X,times([_,_],X,[_,_,_,_]),L),L=[[_,_]]. % blows stack
test('3*x=4',[fail]) :- times([_,_,_],_X,[_,_,_,_]).
test('x*1=1') :- bagof(X,times(X,[],[]),L),L=[[_]].
test('x*2=4') :- bagof(X,times(X,[_,_],[_,_,_,_]),L),L=[[_,_]].
test('1*3=x') :- bagof(X,times(X,[],[]),L),L=[[_]].
test('x*2=x') :- bagof(X,times(X,[_,_],[_,_,_,_]),L),L=[[_,_]].


:- end_tests(times).
```

```
?- run_tests(times).
% PL-Unit: times .......^C
Interrupted test times:'2*x=4'
```

Comment: OMG, thanks so much for taking the time to do this :D